# Android Button match_parent in GridLayout - column doesn't match parent

Tags: android, button, android-gridlayout

So I was changing my LinearLayout into a GridLayout when I encountered a strange and very annoying problem.

Now I am stuck with a Button which seems to have some sort of an unremovable extra spacing and I cant figure out where this came from.

Can someone explain the following screenshots?

Its a very simple 4 column width grid layout: 1 - 2 - 1
And in the center there is an Button and Textview, both width:match_parent but the Button just won't match parent left side..

[image]

[image]

What is going on over here??

**Code:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  style="@style/RootView"

  grid:useDefaultMargins="true"
  grid:columnCount="4"
  grid:rowCount="1" >

  <Space
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
     grid:layout_columnSpan="1"
     grid:layout_gravity="fill" />

  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     grid:layout_columnWeight="2"
     grid:layout_columnSpan="2"
     grid:layout_gravity="fill" >

    <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/logon_btn_text"/>

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/colorGray200"
       android:text="YOLOOO"/>

  </LinearLayout>

  <Space
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_columnSpan="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill" />
```